# Is it possible to create an object that actualize its attributes when modified?

Tags: python, class, attributes

In this example, what should be done so that `print(left_hand.number_of_fingers)` returns `4` and not `5`?

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self, fingers:list):
        self.fingers = fingers
        self.number_of_fingers = len(fingers)

left_hand = Hand(["thumb", "index", "middle", "ring", "pinkie"])
left_hand.fingers.pop()
print(left_hand.number_of_fingers) # I want this to actualize and be 4, not 5
```

I found **a solution using `@property`**

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self, fingers:list):
        self.fingers = fingers

    @property
    def number_of_fingers(self):
        return len(self.fingers)
```

But I'm **not satisfied because of a computational power issue**, if computing `number_of_fingers` was expensive we would only want to compute it whenever `fingers` is modified, not every time the user asks for the attribute `number_of_fingers`.

Now I found **a not elegant solution to solve the issue** with computational power:

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self, fingers:list):
        self.fingers = fingers
        self.old_fingers = fingers
        self.number_of_fingers = len(fingers)

    def get_number_of_fingers(self):
        if self.fingers != self.old_fingers:
            self.old_fingers = self.fingers
            self.number_of_fingers = len(self.fingers)
        return self.number_of_fingers
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the underlying list in your `Hand` class, i.e. `self.fingers`, is not sufficiently encapsulated so that any user can be modifying it, for example by calling `left_hand.fingers.pop()` or even by assigning to it a new list. Therefore, you cannot assume that it has not been modified between calls to `number_of_fingers` and therefore you have no choice but to compute its length in that call.

The solution is to control what clients of your class can and cannot do. The easiest way to do this is by using *name mangling*. That is, you prefix your attribute names with two leading underscore characters. This makes it difficult (although not impossible) for clients of your class to access these attributes from outside of the class (we assume that your users are not intentionally malicious). And therefore we have to provide now a `pop` method:

```py
class Hand:
    def __init__(self, fingers:list):
        self.__fingers = fingers
        self.__number_of_fingers = len(fingers)

    def pop(self):
        assert(self.__fingers)
        self.__number_of_fingers -= 1
        return self.__fingers.pop()

    @property
    def number_of_fingers(self):
        return self.__number_of_fingers

left_hand = Hand(["thumb", "index", "middle", "ring", "pinkie"])
print(left_hand.pop())
print(left_hand.number_of_fingers)
```

Prints:

```
pinkie
4
```

I am *not* suggesting that you actually do the following, but if you wanted to you can get more elaborate by creating special class decorators `@Private` and `@Public` that will wrap your class in a new class and check access to your attributes ensuring that you are not accessing those attributes defined to be private. You use either the `@Private` decorator to define those attributes/methods that are private (everything else is considered public) or the `@Public` decorator to define those attributes/methods that are public (everything else is considered private), but not both. You would typically name your private attributes with a leading single underscore, which is the convention that tells users that the attribute/method is to be considered private.

**This is meant more to catch *inadvertent* access of attributes that are meant to be private. If you execute the code with the *-O* Python flag, then no runtime checks will be made.**

```py
def accessControl(failIf):
    def onDecorator(aClass):
        if not __debug__:
            return aClass
        else:
            class onInstance:
                def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
                    self.__wrapped = aClass(*args, **kargs)

                def __getattr__(self, attr):
                    if failIf(attr):
                        raise TypeError('private attribute fetch: ' + attr)
                    else:
                        return getattr(self.__wrapped, attr)

                def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
                    if attr == '_onInstance__wrapped':
                        self.__dict__[attr] = value
                    elif failIf(attr):
                        raise TypeError('private attribute change: ' + attr)
                    else:
                        setattr(self.__wrapped, attr, value)
            return onInstance
    return onDecorator

def Private(*attributes):
    return accessControl(failIf=(lambda attr: attr in attributes))

def Public(*attributes):
    return accessControl(failIf=(lambda attr: attr not in attributes))

@Private('_fingers', '_number_of_fingers')
class Hand:

    def __init__(self, fingers:list):
        self._fingers = fingers
        self._number_of_fingers = len(fingers)

    def pop(self):
        assert(self._fingers)
        self._number_of_fingers -= 1
        return self._fingers.pop()

    @property
    def number_of_fingers(self):
        return self._number_of_fingers


left_hand = Hand(["thumb", "index", "middle", "ring", "pinkie"])
print(left_hand.pop())
print(left_hand.number_of_fingers)
# Thsis will throw an exception:
print(left_hand._fingers)
```

Prints:

```
pinkie
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(left_hand._fingers)
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 9, in __getattr__
    raise TypeError('private attribute fetch: ' + attr)
TypeError: private attribute fetch: _fingers
```

**Update**

This is the OP's approach using a cache:

```py
class Hand:
    def __init__(self, fingers:list):
        self._cache = {}
        self.fingers = fingers

    def get_number_of_fingers(self):
        fingers = tuple(self.fingers) # can be key of a dictionary
        fingers_length = self._cache.get(fingers)
        if fingers_length:
            print(self.fingers, 'in cache')
            return fingers_length
        fingers_length = len(fingers)
        self._cache[fingers] = fingers_length
        return fingers_length

left_hand_fingers = ["thumb", "index", "middle", "ring", "pinkie"]
right_hand_fingers = ["thumb", "middle", "ring", "pinkie"]

hand = Hand(left_hand_fingers)
print(hand.get_number_of_fingers())
hand.fingers = right_hand_fingers
print(hand.get_number_of_fingers())
hand.fingers = left_hand_fingers
print(hand.get_number_of_fingers())
hand.fingers = right_hand_fingers
print(hand.get_number_of_fingers())
hand.fingers = left_hand_fingers
print(hand.get_number_of_fingers())
```

Prints:

```
5
4
['thumb', 'index', 'middle', 'ring', 'pinkie'] in cache
5
['thumb', 'middle', 'ring', 'pinkie'] in cache
4
['thumb', 'index', 'middle', 'ring', 'pinkie'] in cache
5
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I learnt a couple of things from it, however, even though it solves the example given it does not answer my question, the example was just an illustration. Nevertheless, you gave me an idea on how to solve the problem, I will actualise the question now.

Comment: What I am saying is that if you allow your clients of your class to modify the state of its instances as you currently do by allowing them to directly modify its attributes in arbitrary ways without going through your class's methods, you cannot expect that other attributes whose values functionally depend on those attribute values to be somehow magically updated. (more...)

Comment: Therefore, the solution is to not have your clients do that. Python is not the best language for enforcing that and so certain conventions such as having attributes whose names begin with a leading underscore are understood to be "private" and not to be directly modified by clients. Python is a language meant to be used by gentlemen and ladies.

Comment: I know that I cannot expect that other attributes whose values functionally depend on those attribute values to be somehow magically updated. The question is about what can be done for that to happen without using magic.

Comment: I do not have clients, the code is for my own use. The question is not about privacy is about how to avoid computing something expensive more than once.

Comment: I would then say that your question was not very clear. Perhaps you need to be looking into the topic of *caching*.  For example, when you have an attribute that is the function of n other attributes but is very expensive to compute, maintain a dictionary whose key is a tuple of n input attributes and whose value is the computed result. Every time one or more of your n inputs changes, create a new tuple of the n inputs and check to see if that computation has been done by seeing if the tuple is in the dictionary. If not, you do the expensive computation and add a new dictionary key/value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238795/discussion-between-tereso-del-rio-almajano-and-booboo).

Answer (score 0):

So here in the first code (without using `@property`), you will get the output as 5 and not 4, because you are simply assigning the value of `len(fingers)` to `number_of_fingers` attribute while initialising a `Hand` object, and `number_of_fingers` attribute is not getting linked to `fingers`.

So even if `left_hand.fingers` is modified in between the code, it will have no effect on the value of `number_of_fingers`. One cannot change this behaviour.

Also you don't need that `@property`, I tested and found that there will be no error if it is not written.

And finally coming to

> But I'm not satisfied, because if computing `number_of_fingers` was expensive we would only want to compute it whenever `fingers` is modified, not every time the user asks for the attribute `number_of_fingers`.

Where do you need so much computing power?

Comment: I'm aware that you don't necessarily need to use `@property`, but if it's not used `number_of_fingers` would be a method, not an attribute. And regarding your last question I am working with an algorithm called CAD that has doubly exponential complexity and therefore a lot of computing power is needed there.

Comment: Got it, but as far as I know, I don't think so there is any other better way to do the thing.